# How to make UIView automatically scroll with screen when NavBar scrolls past it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

How can I make a certain element on my screen scroll with the screen (e.i. have a fixed position relative to the screen) when my navbar scrolls past it?

In other words, I have an element that isn't at the top of my screen and you need to scroll down to its position before it starts scrolling with the screen.  Then, when you scroll back up to the top of the screen, the item goes back to its original position and stays there.

I am currently using a UIScrollView to scroll across my screen.  My original plan was to get certain dimensions and basically do something like this when a isScrolling() method is called (pseudocode):

```
if scrolledPositionOnScreen > positionOfUIView {
   scrollUIViewWithRestOfScreen()
} else {
   putUIViewInOriginalPosition()
}
```

However, this doesn't work well when I use different size screens even though I am getting these variables dynamically with respect to screen size.

Is there a delegate or something that will do what I am trying to do/is there an easier, more consistent way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the `UIScrollViewDelegate` delegate from which you can use the `scrollViewDidScroll` method:

```swift
class ViewController : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let frame = CGRect(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 100), size: .init(width: 200, height: 200))
    lazy var v = UIView(frame: frame)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height + 1000)
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.scrollView.addSubview(v)
        self.v.backgroundColor = .red
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > frame.origin.y {
            v.center.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + (v.bounds.height/2)
        }
    }
}
```